# When do you need to capitalize "the" in the name of a journal?

Tags: capitalization

I am writing an article and it just occurred to me that I do not know if I need to capitalize "the" in the name of a journal, be it in the reference section or when written in text. I am using APA guidelines, which says that we need to italicize the name of a journal mentioned in text, so an example would be:

> The latest research published in the *Lancet*....

or

> The latest research published in *The Lancet*....

I did a Google Scholar search and I see it used both ways, though quite more frequently the second way.

I have noticed that some journals include "the" in their names while others don't, and it seems to be only the first type that requires capitalization.  For instance, American Journal of Psychiatry vs The British Journal of Psychiatry. So when referring to the first, you can say it was published in the American Journal of Psychiatry, but when discussing the second, you say the article was published in The British Journal of Psychiatry.

Does this make sense, or am I confusing something?

Comment: Thanks. So there is no consistent logic to it, right, I just need to check whether "the" is included in the journal's name?

Comment: Isn't that logical enough?  You honor the official capitalization of the journal.

Comment: I meant not logical in the sense that it is American Journal of Psychiatry but The British Journal of Psychiatry. But I understand your point.

Comment: I expect you got this point already, but the other factor is, you only capitalize it when it's the first word of the title; something like *Journal of the Association of Mudskippers* doesn't get a capital on *the*.